# How to extract frames of video & apply Imaging SDK filters to it & later save it as video in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c++, video, image-processing, media, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing a Windows Phone 8.1 app. Nokia provides fantastic Imaging SDK to apply filters to images. I want to apply filter to a video file. I searched about it & found [Media Foundation Transform (MFT)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms703138%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). MSDN provided a [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-extensions-sample-7b466096) to apply grey scale filter to video. It's totally based on C++. I am totally unknown to C++.

I think I would extract each frame of video, apply filter to each frame & rejoin them to make it a new video. What approach should I use to do that?

Is there any SDK/library available to extract frames? I have one off-topic question also, can I use any native C++ library in Windows Phone or it must be Windows Phone Runtime Component?

Answer (score 1):

Not C++, but `Windows.Media.Editing` and `Windows.Media.Effects` may be of *some* help to you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.media.editing.Aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.media.effects.aspx

Comment: Not useful at all, it has only slow motion & video stabilization effects.

Answer (score -3):

[Video and Audio file format converion using ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-and-Audio-file-format-conversion)